# How do I get thumbnail generator to recognize the_permalink tag?

Tags: permalinks, thumbnails

Help!

I am trying to create a Digg-clone by integrating "BM Shots" (a webpage thumbnail generator) with "Recommended Links" (a social voting plug-in for Wordpress). Recommended Links allows for user submitted URLs to be displayed via "the_permalink" tag. I'm trying to use BM Shots to generate web page thumbnails based on user submitted URLs. BM Shots work just fine, but I can't get BM Shots to recognize "the_permalink".

The default usage of BM Shots looks like this...

```
            <?php
            $url = 'http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/';
            $width = 300;
            echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
            ?>
```

But I want it to work like this...

```
            <?php
            $url = the_permalink;
            $width = 300;
            echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
            ?>
```

I'm able to get it to work with other Wordpress tags, which is useless, but not "the_permalink." I'm not a coder, so I could use some suggestions, even if they seem obvious.

EDIT//

Here is what the loop looks like

```
            global $wp_query;
            $plugin_settings = get_option( 'reclinks_plugin_settings' );
            $start =  ( $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ) ? 
            ( ( $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] -1 ) * $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] + 1) : 1;
            ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <ol style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:-22px;" start="<?php echo $start; ?>">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li style="margin-top:30px;">
            <img src="<?php
            $url = the_permalink;
            $width = 300;
            echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
            ?>" width="100"  style="float:left;">   
            <h2 style="margin-bottom:-7px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <small> <?php reclinks_favicon(); ?> <?php reclinks_domain(); ?></small>
            <br><small><?php reclinks_votebox(); ?></small>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ol>
            <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'No recommended links yet. Add one?', 'gad_reclinks' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recommended-links/
- http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/bm-shots-automated-screenshots-website/

Comment: "*When I tried using get_permalink() it sent the URL of the posting itself rather than the user submitted URL.*" - please rewrite your question. The *Post Permalink* is clearly **not** what you're after. You need to edit your question to indicate *how you're storing the URL that you want returned*.

Comment: Can you show some code where you want to have the thumbnail and how you get the data now (on your frontpage, right?).

Comment: update: see original posting for my loop code

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you clarify/highlight the part of that code that represents *where the user enters the URL on the front end*?

Comment: `$url = get_permalink();` should work, because `the_permalink();` represents the url in the h2 anchor element. Btw: i would do `<img src="<?php echo bm_mshot (get_permalink(), 300);" width="100" style="float:left;">`

Comment: My bad, forgot to close the php tag > `<img src="<?php echo bm_mshot (get_permalink(), 300); ?>" width="100" style="float:left;">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_permalink()` is actually filtered in the Recommended Links plugin to echo a custom meta field called `_href`. If you want access to that field without echoing it, you can use `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_href', true )`.

Try something like this in your loop:

```
global $post; // may or may not be necessary
$url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_href', true );
$width = 300;
echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help (especially Nathan/goldenapples). Funny enough, I was able to get it working just as goldenapples posted his reply. `<?php echo bm_mshot (gad_reclinks_permalink(), 300); ?>` It turns out both methods work, in case anybody is interested. Anyway, thanks again for all the quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

`the_permalink()` echoes the permalink, `get_permalink()` returns the permalink. So I think using `get_permalink()` will fix your issue.

```
<img src="<?php echo bm_mshot (get_permalink(), 300); ?>" width="100" style="float:left;">
```

Comment: When I tried using get_permalink() it sent the URL of the posting itself rather than the user submitted URL.

Comment: Where is the input coming from? An input field somewhere? Please explain your situation a bit more.

Comment: Visit http://camerabooru.com to see what I'm talking about  - This is my test site so please mind the mess

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question to indicate what you're *actually* doing, because the **Post Permalink** is **not** the URL you're after here.

Comment: But the url is inserted via the_permalink tag

Comment: "*But the url is inserted via the_permalink tag*" - No, it's not. The [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) template tag is used to *echo the post permalink*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code outside the Loop, then `the_permalink()` won't be available. But, I suspect that you're using it within a post, so that shouldn't be a problem.

One major issue: you need to *return* the permalink, not *echo* it. So you don't want to use [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink), but rather [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
<?php
$url = get_permalink;
$width = 300;
echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
?>
```

And if that doesn't work, you might try pulling it out of the `$post` object directly:

```
<?php
global $post;
$url = $post->post_permalink;
$width = 300;
echo bm_mshot ($url, $width);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using it within the loop, in a post. I just tried your suggestion of "pulling it out of the $post object directly," but that didn't work either.